# More efficient pandas python command to drop Nan rows?

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have a DF called TI.  I want to drop rows where BookDate is NaN.  So I run:

```
TI = TI.dropna(subset=['#Book_Date'])
```

When I run this, the memory gets eaten up for some reason (I'm on a 100GB of RAM machine, and about 50% of the RAM is used to hold TI, when I run that dropna line, it goes to 100% usage and never finished executing the commmand).  Is it making a whole new copy?  TI is a 64 million row dataframe, so it needs to be more efficient.

Comment: I think this begs to be asked: what's the RAM usage when you add the parameter `inplace=True`? Note that this means using `TI.dropna(subset=['#Book_Date'], inplace=True)` instead of assigning it to `TI`.

Comment: @Metatron, same problem.  RAM immediately explodes to 100%.

Comment: This is a big problem, it also happens when I run:

TI = TI.drop(colnames[0:2], 1)

Comment: almost all pandas operations create a new copy. You are operating with too limited memory to work with a frame of that size IN MEMORY. You need work on it with chunks.

Comment: @Jeff,  that seems weird that to drop rows I have to create a copy and end up using 2x the RAM.

Comment: well, if you think about it you have to create a new array that is the same size as the existing one, then copy over the non-dropped rows. you don't a-priori know that you have rows to drop. Much easier with a large data set to keep it in HDF5. Then chunk write to a new store, dropping as you go. When you read it back it you are done.

Comment: Ohhh so you mean DROP in chunks?  That might work.

Comment: okay okay -- what about something old school like awk? yeah i know it's not in python -- but sometimes preprocessing steps are easier in the command line

Answer (score 1):

By far the best way to do this is to do this is through employment that the column must be finite. You'll need numpy for this.

```
from pandas import *
import numpy

TI = TI[np.isfinite(TI['#Book_Date'])]
```

Comment: for me, this does not solve the problem in this use case

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `query`, but requires first removing the special character `#` from the column name.

```py
TI = TI.rename(columns={"#Book_Date": "Book_Date"})  # remove the '#' symbol from column name
TI = TI.query("Book_Date.notnull()")  # memory-efficient dropna
```

Based on [Memory-efficient filtering of `DataFrame` rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44437367/memory-efficient-filtering-of-dataframe-rows)