# Memory-efficient filtering of `DataFrame` rows

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

I have a large `DataFrame` object (1,440,000,000 rows). I operate at memory (swap includet) limit.

I need to extract a subset of the rows with certain value of a field. However if i do like that:

```
>>> SUBSET = DATA[DATA.field == value]
```

I end with either `MemoryError` exception or crash.
Is there any way to filter rows explicitely - without calculating intermediate mask (`DATA.field == value`)?

I have found [DataFrame.filter()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) and [DataFrame.select()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select.html#pandas.DataFrame.select) methods, but they operate on column labels/row indices rather than on the row data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), it should be a bit faster:

```
df = df.query("field == value")
```

Comment: I doubt that `DataFrame.query()` is faster. It is 3x slower when tested on a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

If by any change all the data in the DataFrame are of same types, use numpy array instead, it's more memory efficient and faster. You can convert your dataframe to numpy matrix by df.as_matrix().

Also that you might wanna check how much memory the dataframe already takes by:

```
    import sys
    sys.getsizeof()
```

that returns the size in bytes.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not what I am asking about. Types of my field are different (`int`, `float` and `str` - wor which i use `dtype="category"`)